# Verify another class' method inside a mockito spy

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have two classes that works one inside of the other

```
public class Class1 {
    public Class1(){}

    public void myMethod(List<String> list){
        for (String element: list){
            Class2 class2 = new Class2(element);
            class2.anotherMethod();
        }
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    private final String element;

    public Class2(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void anotherMethod(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

My question is how can I spy Class1 and check that when I call class1.myMethod, the class2 object is created *once for each element in the list* and the anotherMethod called in the same block?

I'm using Java 11 and Mockito 3.5, and can't change the project's POM.

Comment: Could you fix `mymethod`?  There's no return type.

Comment: Sure, it's void.

Comment: Not possible as is.  Change Class1 to inject a Class2Factory, and use the factory to create an instance of Class2.  The test would inject a Spy'd Factory, and verify it was invoked list.size() times.

Comment: I don't understand the proposal. Could you write an example?

Comment: You don't have Powermock? You could mock the constructor.

Comment: No Powermock in the project

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is design issue for mocking construction of object, refactor for testability should be a better solution. (e.g. inject Class2Factory to class as suggested by [Andrew S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650475/andrew-s))

But if refactoring is not feasible,
we can make use of [Mocking Object Construction](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.6/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction)

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockConstruction;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedConstruction;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Class1Test {
    @Test
    void myMethod_createClass2PerItemAndCall_anotherMethod() {
        try (MockedConstruction<Class2> mocked = mockConstruction(Class2.class, (mock, context) -> {
            // simulate the construction, in case you want to verify construction argument
            when(mock.getElement()).thenReturn((String) context.arguments().get(0));
        })) {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            class1.myMethod(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

            List<Class2> mockedInstances = mocked.constructed();
            assertEquals(3, mockedInstances.size());
            // in case construction argument checking is needed
            assertEquals("a", mockedInstances.get(0).getElement());
            assertEquals("b", mockedInstances.get(1).getElement());
            assertEquals("c", mockedInstances.get(2).getElement());
            verify(mockedInstances.get(0)).anotherMethod();
            verify(mockedInstances.get(1)).anotherMethod();
            verify(mockedInstances.get(2)).anotherMethod();
        }
    }

}

public class Class2 {
    ...

    // for verify constructor argument
    String getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}
```